# PHPActiveRecord group option breaks count function

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I have a PHP ActiveRecord model in which I have a function that requires the number of rows a query will return.  I obtain the number of rows using the built in `static::count($conditions)` function.  This works well and good but the issue arises when I include a GROUP BY statement.  When I include this the count returns 1.  I examined the resulting SQL and it was similar to

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM TABLE
 /* JOINS */
 /* WHERE CONDITIONS */
 GROUP BY `field`
```

When I ran the query manually I get

```
 1
 1
 1
```

.
.
.
     1

```
 (1,000 times since there are 1,000 rows in the DB)
```

When I remove the GROUP BY statement, I get the value 1,000 like I should.

Obviously this occurs since COUNT is an aggregate function and it doesn't play well with group by.  So with that being said, how can I return the correct number of rows using activerecord with a group by?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I followed the example set by @jvenema in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11478349/1943591), wherein one defines a `BaseModel` class to override default `ActiveRecord\Model` behavior. Your models will then extend the `BaseModel` class.

```
class BaseModel extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    public static function count(/* ... */)
    {

        $args = func_get_args();
        $options = static::extract_and_validate_options($args);

        // Call the original function if $options['group'] is undefined
        if ( !array_key_exists('group', $options) )
        return call_user_func_array( 'parent::count', func_get_args() );

        // This might fail if the table has a `counts` column
        $options['select'] = 'COUNT(*) as counts';

        if (!empty($args) && !is_null($args[0]) && !empty($args[0]))
        {
            if (is_hash($args[0]))
                $options['conditions'] = $args[0];
            else
                $options['conditions'] = call_user_func_array('static::pk_conditions',$args);
        }

        $table = static::table();
        $sql = $table->options_to_sql($options);
        $values = $sql->get_where_values();

        // Again, this might fail if there is a table named `tmp`
        $wrapper = "SELECT COUNT(counts) FROM ({$sql->to_s()}) as tmp";

        // Casting to (int) is optional; remove if it causes problems
        return (int) static::connection()->query_and_fetch_one($wrapper,$values);
    }
}
```

This function will fire only if `$options['group']` is set. Additionally, note that this executes a `COUNT()` of rows created by `GROUP BY` rather than a `SUM()`. This is meant to account for cases when `$has_many` and `$options['joins']` are in play, so as to prevent double-counting when `INNER JOIN` returns multiple results for an association.

Comment: You'll need the [is_hash](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/function-is_hash/) function for this code to work.